# What sense could have this code?

Tags: c++, opencv

I´m studing the code of OpenCV, and I came across the next few lines:

The function´s var are:

```
CvMat* _err;
CvMat* _mask;
int i, count = _err->rows*_err->cols, goodCount = 0;
 for( i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    goodCount += mask[i] = err[i] <= threshold;    // This line is strange for me
return goodCount;
```

What does the line I indicated actually do? Because, call me strange, I have never seen anything like that.

For your information:

- Yes, the code is working :D
- The code is part of the `CvModelEstimator2::findInliers` function.

Comment: This code uses unitialised pointers.

Comment: Yes, that line is horrible, and shouldn't be written like that.

Comment: Where do _err and _mask get initialized?  Are we missing some code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That line is **evil**.

Nevertheless, it assigns `1` to `mask[i]` if `err[i] <= threshold` and `0` otherwise.

Then it increments `goodCount` if the condition holds.

```
mask[i] = (err[i] <= threshold);
goodCount += mask[i];
```

Answer (score 4):

So you're confused about this line:

```
goodCount += mask[i] = err[i] <= threshold;
```

You can use a C operator precedence table to figure out the order of operations here, but it's fairly unambiguous anyway:

1. Compare err[i] against threshold.  This results in a bool (true or false).
2. Assign the result to mask[i].  I think the bool will be converted to a number here, which will be 1 for true or 0 for false.
3. Use the new value of mask[i] (which is the result of the `=` operator) to increment goodCount (basically, goodCount will end up containing the count of "true" values found in step 1).

To me the most subtle part of that line is the fact that assignment returns a reference to the left-hand side (i.e. the target).  This is sometimes seen in a less complex expression like this:

```
if ((mem = malloc(42)) == NULL)
    throw ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
goodCount += mask[i] = err[i] <= threshold;
```

Mixing assignment and comparison in the same statement is generally a bad idea.

The recommended approach is to (1) know what is the precedence of the involved operators, and (2) split the statement into several ones, to enhance readability.